# How can I create a mapping template to map path parameter to lambda function in apigateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using serverless to deploy API gateway and lambda using `lambda integration`. Below is the infra code:

```
myLambda:
   ...
   events:
    - http:
        path: customer/{id}
        method: delete
        integration: lambda
        request:
          parameters:
            paths:
              id: true
          template:
            text/plain: "$input.params('id')"
```

It creates a `delete` API to delete customer based on the `id` specified in the path parameter. I'd like to map the `path id` to myLambda's event parameter in its handler. But the above code doesn't work the lambda receives the whole http request from API gateway. How can I map the `id` parameter to the event parameter in lambda?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using API Gateway and Lambda functions, you have 2 options:

1. Lambda proxy
2. Lambda integration

By default, the Serverless framework is using Lambda proxy. This way of connecting to a Lambda function is a lot quicker. It passes the whole HTTP request to a Lambda function and it lets you handle the request completely on the Lambda function side.

There is another way, as I mentioned, it's Lambda integration, without using Lambda proxy. If you want to use this method, you need to set up mappings on your request and your response. This way is "cleaner" on the LAmbda code side, because Lambda received mapped parameters in the event, compared to the whole HTTP request as in proxy. On the other hand, this kind of integration is more complicated to set up, as you need to make all the mappings, and it uses VTL (Apache Velocity Template Language) to do that.

In order to set this up using Serverless, take a look at the "Lambda Integration" section in [Serverless framework API Gateway documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#lambda-integration):

Comment: I have set `lambda integration` in the API gateway. The question is how to map the path parameter to lambda event?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that ApiGateway event itself should contain that query / path parameter key value pair and you can directly query your parameters from the event, if you'd go with Lambda Proxy method which @Caldazar mentioned above.

For eg let's say if you have a URL

https://example.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/confirmReg?token=12345&uid=5

you could simply retrieve the values as below from your handler:

```
token = event['queryStringParameters']['token']
uid = event["queryStringParameters"]['uid']
```

**EDIT**:

Please follow the below steps for Lambda Integration:

Go to your respective API resource method and click on Integration Request section

[image]

Find the Mapping Templates area of the Integration request and open it up. Add a new mapping template for the application/json Content-Type. You'll need to change the type in the combo box from "Input passthrough" to "Mapping Template".

Then paste the following piece of JSON inside the template:

```
{
  "id" : "$input.params('id')"
}
```

This way you'll not end up receiving the entire event object inside your lambda but only your path param which is sent in your request.

Some references: [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) & [2](https://medium.com/@lakshmanLD/lambda-proxy-vs-lambda-integration-in-aws-api-gateway-3a9397af0e6d)

Comment: I am using `lambda integration` so I don't want to see the whole http request in lambda code. How to map the path parameter to lambda event?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao I've updated the answer, please check and let me know if it works for you

Comment: I can make it work but the event in lambda still includes everything in the request like `body`, `header` etc. What I really want is to only get the id as a string parameter in lambda.